# Which form is more simplified? $\frac{x-2\sqrt{xy}-y}{x-y}$ or $1-\frac{2\sqrt{xy}}{x-y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which of the following is more simplified, for two rational numbers $x$ and $y$?

$$\frac{x-2\sqrt{xy}-y}{x-y} \qquad \text{or} \qquad 1-\frac{2\sqrt{xy}}{x-y}$$

Sorry for the lack of context; not really much context to give...

Comment: There is not a standard definition of what "simplified" means.  Is there some particular definition or context you have in mind?

Comment: @EricWofsey No, just wondering which form is better, for example for simplified forms, (at least for math contests) people use simplified improper fractions, no radicals in denominators, etc

Comment: In my opinion neither is preferable (meaning one isn't better than the other).

Comment: @suomynonA Your concern about "no radicals in the denominator" is misguided because what if $x$ and/or $y$ is irrational?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Why did I get a downvote though? If you think the question should be improved just comment...

Comment: @Jared no radicals in the denominators assuming the radicand is rational

Comment: @suomynonA Your response made no sense.  You stated: 

"...no radicals in denominators..."

yet you have $x$ and $y$ which could be _any_ irrational numbers.  While it should always be possible to "rationalize" the denominator, it's not at all, straightforward--you certainly cannot do it, uniformly, for any $x$, $y$, irrational numbers.

Comment: @Jared edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the second
because it has fewer terms.

Another choice might be
to replace the second term by

$\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x/y}-\sqrt{y/x}}
$.